# Getting Facebook HTML login page instead of CSV file

Tags: python, facebook

I'm trying to make a tool that exports Facebook Lead result .csv to Google Sheets.

Trying to get CSV file of lead data from Facebook using their faceboot-python-business-sdk.

Already successfully got id, export link, locale, name, and status list but when I'm trying to download using that 'export link' the response is a facebook login page instead of .csv file.

When trying to open this link in logged in browser, it's downloading .csv file as expected

I'm doing something wrong for sure, but idk what exactly.

Here is code:

```
FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)
my_account = AdAccount('act_%account_number%')
leads = my_account.get_lead_gen_forms()
for lead in leads:
    if(lead['status'] == 'ACTIVE'):        
        response = requests.get(lead['leadgen_export_csv_url'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your api rate limits (Or just try to wait an hour)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting/

Comment: In fact, I'm first faced with that problem 5-6 hours ago, and since that trying to find some answer, sometimes checking, and it's still a problem. 
Rate limits has no effect, problem appears even if only one file requested.